# Unable to mount Windows ntfs partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I have a computer that is dual booting with Windows 8, and Ubuntu 12.10. Everything works fine I am able to boot into both OS's as expected.

But when I try to boot into Ubuntu, and mount the Windows partition I get the following error:

[image]

Can someone please help me remedy the problem?

Comment: Was your windows hibernated before you booted into Ubuntu?

Comment: No it was completely shut down... but I wonder if the hybrid shut-down thing is causing the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's very likely, you need to use full shutdown in win 8 to properly close the ntfs file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, hybrid shutdown is using the hiberfil.sys, the explanation is here:

http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/152937-what-is-hybrid-boot-in-windows-8-and-how-does-it-work/

The guide with instructions on how to disable it is here:

http://www.techulator.com/resources/5201-How-enable-or-disable-Hybrid-Boot-Windows.aspx

Don't remove the hibernation file, it will cause data loss!

Answer (score 1):

As others have not-so-explicitly said, windows 8 does not shut down when you click shutdown.  Instead, it goes into hibernation mode, so it boots more quickly. You have two choices to have it shutdown normally (as far as I know, as I am a windows 7 user):

1. Reboot
2. Hard shutdown (hold down the power button until the machine is completely powered off)

Answer (score 0):

You need to boot windows and then reboot it.

NTFS has a journal that if not written to will appear as not cleanly dismounted and Linux, to avoid potential destruction of Data will refuse to mount it.

Comment: I have tried this about a million times...

Comment: If windows isn't hibernated and you have rebooted it, then you can remove hiberfile.sys.
http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-delete-hibernation-file-hiberfil-sys/

Then once mounted in Ubuntu you can probably switch it back by running those steps in reverse.

Comment: I'll give that a go next time I boot into Windows, I will let you know how it goes.